# Dynamic DFP Javascript

Tags: javascript, ads, google-dfp

I'm sure this has been asked and answered before but I haven't been able to track down an answer so I'm asking again.

I'm trying to implement Google DFP. I was able to dynamically create inline javascript that was serving ads, so I know the admin side should be configured correctly.

We don't have any inline JS in our application though, so I'm trying to build it out dynamically with JS and I haven't had much luck.

I've pasted my JS [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jxurf). Worth noting is that the top part (prior to /////   !EVENTS) is loaded immediately, whereas the bottom part is loaded inside a $(document).ready() call in case that could be a culprit.

The idea with the code is that each advertisement div has data attributes with the url, size, and id of the advertisement. Using this I loop through each add, defining the slot, once all slots are defined, I display all slots, and once that happens, I call the remaining DFP functions. Sounds like it should work (to me anyway), but its not.

Each console.log() call is occurring as expected, and when I inspect the googletag object logged by that last call, the debug log contains entries like: "Created slot: /[userid]/[ad div id]","Google service JS loaded","Created service: publisher_ads", "Associated publisher_ads service with slot /[userid]/[ad unit id]"; for each record.

I'm not sure if perhaps the Google service JS or created service calls happening for each ad unit is causing problems or expected behaviours, but nothing is being logged to the console except what I've logged and there doesn't seem to be any indication that I've found that something has gone wrong, its just not serving ads.

In the documentation, and in the version of the implementation I had working, there were inline scripts that did the display calls. I'm not sure if perhaps this has to be handled inline and somehow displays the results in the parent of the script tag that called it or something, but even when I make the display calls inline it isn't working, with no more or less logging going on, which leads me to believe something isn't working correctly during the defineSlot() step, but like I mentioned the googletag object's debuglog does indicate the slot was defined.

In my network pane, it seems that there is two calls to Google at http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_ads_gpt.js and http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js which returns the required Javascript, but those are the only calls to Google being made (relating to ads, there is other analytics calls) and there are 4 ads on this page that should be loading so I would expect there would be more calls if the ads were actually attempting to be served.

Needless to say I'm at a loss. I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but I haven't worked much with DFP, or ads at all really, so I'm not sure where else to look to track this down.

Thanks in advance for any direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually got a working script which I'm pretty sure does what you are after.

https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js

You should be able to get some pointers from [my script](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/blob/master/jquery.dfp.js) but just from looking at your codepen, one issue which I have spotted is that you are not using the actual DOM id of the adunit div which DFP will need. Anywhere you are using:

```
$(that).attr('data-id');
```

should be:

```
$(that).attr('id');
```

The calls to `googletag.display` also need to come after

```
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(); 
googletag.enableServices();
```

Comment: I actually have a data attribute with the id as well as the id itself. Adding the DOM to the codepen would have been helpful. I suppose its redundant to duplicate but I try to keep data that I'll use in my scripts attached to data attributes and use the id attribute just as a selector.

I've moved those calls above the display calls and it seems to have changed but still isn't rendering. Now a call to http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads from google_ads_gpt returns error 400. In the debug_log it fetches gpt, delays each ad, recieves gpt, calls fillslot for each ad. No rendered ads.

Comment: I just dropped in your script and it works great. I've added the MIT text to it in the comments above the script. I tried browsing through it and trying to see if I could spot something I was doing wrong from it but it seems the easiest thing to do would be to use this rather than rolling my own. I don't know what future options we may make use of and you seem to already accounted for targeting and things I haven't started to consider. Thanks for the quick reply and the great script. Its a huge help.

Comment: Cool glad it's working for you... feel free to fork it and strip it back down to the basics if it is doing a bit more than you need at the moment... but yeah the targeting stuff is quite useful!